# !Why is blender rendering different from what you see in the view?

Tags: animation

I'm new to blender, just started with skeleton and animation, and now I'm facing a problem.

The animation I made in another file is imported into the scene I need, but the rendered view is different from the displayed view. I don’t know where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your render settings?

It also might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your pictures my guess would be that your "render" button is not activated on your modifier or your outliner. Share your file using this link: https://blend-exchange.com/ for more accurate answer.

Here the render option is greyed out, meaning you will se your cube in the viewport but not in the render[image]

Here you will see one cube on the render because the render option is greyed out on the modifier (That is if your render button is not greyed out in the outliner see first picture)

[image]